# .net Remoting Concurrent server

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create a concurrent server in Remoting(C#) such that it can handle 10 clients at a time. It would ask a question to all 10 at the same time and records the response time of each client. The one with the least time will then be able to play a game with the server. Can anyone help or guide me as to how can I approach towards achieving server concurrency or if any other alternative is there??

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I'd tend to use non blocking(async) APIs and make the server code single threaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you have each client call a webservice on the server X number of times, and go with the fastest average time.  Kind of like a ping.

Edit, I've just had a look and there is a [ping class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx).  Maybe that could help.

Comment: Thanks Phil for the answer, but I also want to know which clients answered the Question correctly and choose the fastest among them.

Comment: Ok, how about implementing the observer pattern? http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternObserver.aspx